# open two windows when click on print Codeigniter, Javascript

Tags: javascript, codeigniter

I made this JS function that open 2 pages

```
 function edit(id){
    window.open('<?php echo site_url();?>store_out/store_out_print/'+id);
    window.open('<?php echo site_url();?>store_out/delivery_print/'+id);
    document.getElementById('print').target = '_blank';
}
```

I have that table that display all possible records that user can select one row and click on print image so two pages are opened:

```
 <?php
         for($i=0;$i<sizeof($storeout);$i++){ ?>
   <tr class="gradeZ" id="<?php echo $storeout[$i]->storeout_id;?>" onclick="edit(this.id); ">
                <td><?php printf("%06d",$i+1);?></td>
                <td><?php echo $storeout[$i]->storeout_id;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $storeout[$i]->storeout_modified_time;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $account[$i][0]->account_name;?></td>
                <td><?php echo $storeout[$i]->rof_id != 0 ? "R.O.F" : "S.O";?></td>


            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
```

I want when I select specific row and click on the print image, execute two functions to open two different pages (delivery/store_out).

Any Ideas guys?

Comment: Could you post the code that attaches the click event to the button?

Comment: POP UP BLOCKERS! Have fun telling people how to add your site to the exception list.

Comment: @justin, it's not button it's a clickable image :

<td width="5%"><a id="print" href="#" ><img src="<?php echo site_url();?>/images/print.png" border="0" title="Print" height="25" width="25"/> </a></td>

Comment: @imanhamaad Sorry, I just meant that it was clickable, that's all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to assume that the `td` is in a `tr` which is programmatically generated in a loop (i.e. you will have more than 1 `tr`, `td`, and `img`). I will also assume jQuery is available.

The first problem will be if you have more than 1 row that is created in a loop, you will have a bunch of things with the same `id="print"`. This is not the good js.

You should append the `store_out` (or whatever the id is you are trying to get to the controller) to the id attribute. Something like `id="print_<?php echo $thing->id;?>"`. This will let you get the id you want to pass to the edit function. I would also add a `class="print"` which will make the below easier. So, the whole row would look something like:

```
<td width="5%"><a id="print_<?php echo $thing->id; ?>" class="print" href="#" ><img src="<?php echo site_url();?>/images/print.png" border="0" title="Print" height="25" width="25"/> </a></td>
```

Which would output something like:

```
<td width="5%"><a id="print_1234" class="print" href="#" ><img src="http://example.com/images/print.png" border="0" title="Print" height="25" width="25"/> </a></td>
```

Second is you are not passing the `id` to the method so far as I can tell. Considering you heeded the above, you can pull the id from the id attribute.

```
$('.print').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id').split('_')[1];
    edit(id);
})
```

Comment: Thanks but I am sending the ID from another <tr> which means I have to trigger the function from that <tr> I am sending the id from and in the same time execute the function when click on print image... any ideas ??

Comment: No. Edit your question and add all of the relevant code. That will help me help you.

Comment: It didn't post properly. Can you fix it? Wrap all of the code by highlighting and pressing the '{}' button.

Comment: Thanks for fixing the formatting. I don't see where the problem is though. The code you have should trigger the `edit` function when you click on the `tr`. What isn't working? Also, you shouldn't accept the answer until it is actually answered correctly -- this will get other people looking at the question too.